# <div> page split blocks other things on page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally split a page in half. When I use the code below, it does split the page, but it also covers all other things I already had on the page. Is there another way to achieve the page split while still being able to see everything else?

```css
#top,
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

#top {
  top: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean it cover other things ?

Comment: not sure what you're going for exactly. Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmGmVv

Comment: I think you want to move your current content inside one of the two divs (top + bottom) so you can see it? When elements are positioned fixed they will cover the content you already had in the page

Comment: Sorry, I guess i should have put the entire code. It covers anything I have between the <body> and </body> tags.

Comment: Check my answer, i think it's resolve your issue.

Comment: It solved my problem, Thanks!

Comment: You should use a gradient as the background on `body` if you just want one color for the first half of the page and another color for the second half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `z-index:-1;` in  `#top and #bottom` id.

```css
#top,
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top {
  top: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
<p>
  Hello
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="top_div">Contents</div>
<div class="bottom_div">Contents</div>


css:

.top_div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 370px;
    background-color: blue
}
.bottom_div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: crimson;
}
```